# find command characteristics on unix

Tags: unix, find

How can I delete from directory2 and directory3 some files in the same time using the find command?

Some files of directory1 valides the same characteristics of the files in the 2 others directory and directories 1,2,3 figures in the directory0.

Comment: You need to come up with some characteristics that are only valid for the files you want to delete and invalid for every other file.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you meant:

```
(cd directory1 | find -iname 'somename' -print0) |
    tee >(cd directory2 && xargs -0 rm -fvi) |
    tee >(cd directory3 && xargs -0 rm -fvi)
```

ad libitum? But I'll make the answer more specific once you do your question

Comment: i'm sorry but this is the right question :How can i Search all empty files of **non-root system** and try to delete them ?

Comment: And what would 'non-root system' mean? You mean, other mountpoints? You mean other owner than root? You mean something else?

Comment: no,i mean that in the / directory there is the root which i don't like to apply the command of find on it ?

Answer (score 0):

To find (From the man examples)

```
find / -newerct '1 minute ago' -print
             Print out a list of all the files whose inode change 
             time is more recent than the current time minus one minute
```

To remove

```
find / -newerct '1 minute ago' -print | xargs rm
```

Comment: Aha "in the same time"... you have excellent question detection skills